# animated gifs of (sorting) algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graphics

What is the best way to generate gifs of algorithms like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in Wikipedia? In Linux, any language really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably more user-friendly ways, but last time I did this, I used [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) to assemble some pre-built frames into an animation.

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks to all. All good answers that I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can construct [animations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) by assembling several bitmaps into one:

```
convert -delay 100 \
      -page first.gif \
      -page second.gif \
      -page third.gif \
      -loop 0  animation.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to generate animated gifs with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) if you prefer a GUI tool. Plenty of how-to's if you [google it](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGGE_elGR409GR415&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=create%20animated%20gif%20with%20gimp#sclient=psy&hl=el&rlz=1C1GGGE_elGR409GR415&source=hp&q=create%20animated%20gif%20with%20gimp&pbx=1&oq=create%20animated%20gif%20with%20gimp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l2719l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dd352a532221861a&biw=1280&bih=897).